# How to disable the default bundling in angular CLI with Angular 4

Tags: javascript, angular, webpack, angular-cli

I am new to `webpack` and `angular-cli`. My problem is that when I create an Angular 4 project using `angular-cli`, everything works fine with `ng-serve` but everything get bundled by default. Web pack bundling info:

[image: Web pack bundling info]

I am not able to see the component.ts files in browser to debug. Is there any way to disable the bundling? `angular-cli` version details:

[image: Angular CLI version Details]

Comment: You can see the .ts file in the browser. You need to find the line you want in the bundle(most likely main.js). If you add a debug point there, it will use the sourcemaps to place a debug pointer in your component.ts file.

Comment: Another way to accomplish this in dev would be to put a debugger; statement in your ts file.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

When you do `ng serve` with the CLI, it will create sourcemap files by default. That means, that although the source files are bundled together, you can view the original source files in the debugger and step through them.
You find them in the DevTools under the tab Sources, the folder webpack://

[image: Sourcemaps in DevTools]

If you want to view your prod build like this, you can add the flag -sm for sourcemaps. In the prod build, there won't be sourcemaps by default.

```
ng serve --prod -sm
```

Answer (score 1):

Yes also you can enable and disable this from the developer tool option 
Go to setting  (press F12 then F1 ). Under the source you can enable and disable to source mapping. In deploy time you not going to put the map file so this will not get downloaded.
[Developer tool settings](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6mSOi.png)

Answer (score -1):

Use following build command to hide your source code under Sources Tab

`ng build  --no-sourcemap`  ( Development environment )

`ng build --env=prod  --no-sourcemap` (Production environment)

Comment: Please explain what your command does and format it so it is easier to read (https://stackoverflow.com/help/formatting)